# Qué hacer si mysql da error en Xampp con windows 10?

Tags: mysql

El Xampp versión 7.3.11-0-VC15 en mi ordenador con windows 10 hasta hoy funcionaba perfecto y hoy el módulo mysql me da este error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.This may be due to a blocked port,missing dependencies,improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method, Press the Logs button to view error logs and check, the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this, entire log window on the fórums.
No sé que hacer? Alguien pudiera ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

1. revisa el log de mysql
2. revisa que no este otro ejecutable corriendo en ese puerto
3. revisa que no este bloqueando el firewall

Comment: Hola, gracias por su colaboración. Pero le soy sincera, no soy desarrolladora de web, estoy aprendiendo para poder hacer una página de mi trabajo. Sería tan amable de decirme cuando accedo al log de MySQL, cómo detecto otro ejecutable corriendo en este puerto. Gracias nuevamente, un saludo

Comment: Debes revisar el panel control de XAMPP, veras botones para cada componente, si aun necesitas mas ayuda ....